# Reboot after power failure for Mac running Ubuntu (server)

Tags: ubuntu, mac

I have Ubuntu 10.04.1 (Lucid) running on a 2010 Mac Mini (4,1).  It's a server, so I want it to be able to restart after a power failure ("server mode").

In Mac OS X, you can check "Start up automatically after a power failure" in the "Energy Saver" System Preferences.  However, having this value checked doesn't seem to effect "server mode" behavior in Ubuntu (that is, it won't restart after a power failure).

This seems to be because the "server mode" value isn't persisted in pram/efi, but gets set by Mac OS X on every boot.

I found [this tutorial](http://mythic-beasts.com/support/macminicolo_howto.html) on how to turn on "server mode" for a Mac Mini, but it doesn't work:

```
$ setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0
setpci: Warning: No devices selected for `0xa4.b=
```

A lot has changed with the new 4,1 Mac Minis-- just getting Ubuntu installed on it was quite a feat.  Perhaps the "server mode" incantation has changed also?

My question is: how do I enable "server mode" on the new 4,1 Mac Minis?

Comment: Before voting to close, see: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/968/why-was-my-question-about-mac-mini-servers-closed

Comment: wow did this get reopened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answered buried in [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7620648&postcount=2).  The new setpci command is

```
sudo setpci -s 00:03.0 0x7b.b=19
```

btw, this setting isn't "sticky" and won't persist across reboots-- it has to be set upon each boot.

You can put this command in a bash script and run it on startup.  See [here](http://tinyurl.com/23akpr6) for details on start-up scripts.